# ios searchbar textfield background not correct as setup color

Tags: ios, searchbar

When I change the background color of textfield inside UISearchBar, I see that the color is not correctly set. For example: I set color `#2B2F6A`, but it changes to `#343869`.

Any suggestions for this? Thanks a lot.

```
Code:
iOS < 13

if let textField = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
    if let backgroundView = textField.subviews.first {
      backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 28.0/255.0, green: 28.0/255.0, blue: 28.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

iOS 13:

```
self.searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 28.0/255.0, green: 28.0/255.0, blue: 28.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

the set color likely grey but the result look like black

Comment: on which iOS version you are checking this?

Comment: Could you provide some example code when you have set the colour?

Answer (score 0):

On iOS13, even though the UISearchBar property searchTextField of type UISearchTextField  is a UITextField subclass and in [the related session of WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/) there is a claim that developers can customize the textField property just like they can with a UITextField, there are some properties that do not keep respect this "contract". For example changing rightView is not customisable. Presumably this is also the case with backgroundColor.

Update: I had a check, I can set the backgroundColor without any issue on iOS13 - are you using the searchTextField property?